# Como abrir a webcam em uma maquina local por uma página php no servidor?

Tags: php, jquery

Pessoal estou tentando criar uma página no chrome que abre a webcam estou usando a biblioteca webcam.js no IE11 o código funciona porém no chrome e no firefox não aparece a mensagem Movie is not loaded yet nos dois navegadores e não abre a webcam vocês já tiveram esse problema.

segue o código que estou usando:

index.php

```
<style type="text/css">
    /* jQuery lightBox plugin - Gallery style */
    #cuadro_camara {
        background-color: #444;
        padding-left: 30px;
        padding-top:20px;
    }
    #titulo_camara {
    background-color: #666;
    color:#FFF;
    padding-left: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align:center;
    }
    .botones_cam {
        background-color:#FFF;
        color:#333;
        font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
        font-size:14px;
        margin-top:10px;
        width:100px;
        height:40px;
    }
    .formulario {
        color: #FFF;
    }

    </style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="webcam.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        webcam.set_api_url( 'test.php' );//PHP adonde va a recibir la imagen y la va a guardar en el servidor
        webcam.set_quality( 90 ); // calidad de la imagen
        webcam.set_shutter_sound( true ); // Sonido de flash
    </script>
        <script language="JavaScript">
        webcam.set_hook( 'onComplete', 'my_completion_handler' );

        function do_upload() {
            // subir al servidor
            document.getElementById('upload_results').innerHTML = '<h1>Cargando al servidor...</h1>';
            webcam.upload();
        }

        function my_completion_handler(msg) {

            if (msg.match(/(http\:\/\/\S+)/)) {
                var image_url = RegExp.$1;//respuesta de text.php que contiene la direccion url de la imagen

                // Muestra la imagen en la pantalla
                document.getElementById('upload_results').innerHTML = 
                    '<img src="' + image_url + '">'+
                    '<form action="gestion_foto.php" method="post">'+
                    '<input type="hidden" name="id_foto" id="id_foto" value="' + image_url + '"  /><br>'+
                    '<label>Nombre </label><input type="text" name="nombre_foto" id="nombre_foto"/>'+
                    '<label>Descripcion </label><input type="text" name="des" id="des"/>'+
                    '<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Enviar" /></form>'
                    ;
                // reset camera for another shot
                webcam.reset();
            }
            else alert("PHP Error: " + msg);
        }
    </script>
<div align="left" id="cuadro_camara">    

<table width="100%" height="144"><tr><td width="100" valign=top>
        <form>
        <input type=button value="Configurar" onClick="webcam.configure()" class="botones_cam">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type=button value="Tomar foto" onClick="webcam.freeze()" class="botones_cam">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type=button value="subir" onClick="do_upload()" class="botones_cam">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type=button value="Reset" onClick="webcam.reset()" class="botones_cam">
    </form>

    </td>
    <td width="263" valign=top>
    <script language="JavaScript">
    document.write( webcam.get_html(320, 240) );//dimensiones de la camara
    </script>
    </td>
    <td width=411>
        <div id="upload_results" class="formulario" > </div>
  </td></tr></table><br /><br />
</div>



<br />
<br />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#gallery a').lightBox();//Galeria jquery
    });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    /* jQuery lightBox plugin - Gallery style */
    #gallery {
        background-color: #444;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #gallery ul { list-style: none; }
    #gallery ul li { display: inline; }
    #gallery ul img {
        border: 5px solid #3e3e3e;
        border-width: 5px 5px 5px;
    }
    #gallery ul a:hover img {
        border: 5px solid #fff;
        border-width: 5px 5px 5px;
        color: #fff;
    }
    #gallery ul a:hover { color: #fff; }
    </style>

    <div id="gallery">
    <ul>
  <?php  

  include("clase_conexion.php");
  $consulta="select * from fotos order by id_foto desc";
  $busca_fotos=mysql_query($consulta,$c);
  while($ro=mysql_fetch_array($busca_fotos)){
   $url=$ro['id_foto'];  
   $nombre=$ro['nombre']; 
     $des=$ro['des'];
     echo "<li>

            <a href=\"fotos/".$url.".jpg\" title=\"$nombre - $des\">

                <img src=\"fotos/".$url.".jpg\" width=\"150\" height=\"120\" alt=\"\" />

            </a>
        </li>";
  }
?>    
    </ul>
</div>


test.php

<?php

include("clase_conexion.php");
$id_foto=date('YmdHis');//extraemos la fecha del servidor
$consulta="insert into fotos values ('$id_foto','','')";
$inserta_foto=mysql_query($consulta,$c);
$filename = "fotos/".$id_foto.'.jpg';//nombre del archivo
$result = file_put_contents( $filename, file_get_contents('php://input') );//renombramos la fotografia y la subimos
if (!$result) {
    print "No se pudo subir al servidor\n";
    exit();
}

$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) . '/' . $filename;//generamos la respuesta como la ruta completa
print "$url\n";//20120214060943.jpg

?>
```

Comment: Se o código funcionou no IE e no chrome e firefoz não, essa biblioteca não deve ser muito atualizada, e deve usar algo que a maioria dos navegadores já retirou por ser obsoleto

Comment: você conhece alguma biblioteca que funcione no chrome ou firefox que faz isso

Comment: Não, nunca fiz nada usando a webcam, boa sorte

Comment: Beleza já conseguir aqui

Comment: Se já encontrou a solução, poste uma resposta, outros usuários podem ter o mesmo problema. Você poderá aceitar a sua própria resposta dentro de 2 dias